# Installing Scipy for Windows

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to install Scipy on my computer. I did it by using the command pip install Scipy. (pip & numpy are up-to-date and I am using Python 3.6) I also tried it with Pycharm, but it didn't worked either.

I always do get this Error:

> Command
>   "c:\users***\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c
>   "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-x3s21920\scipy\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-gr9ppj_q-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users***\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-x3s21920\scipy\

Does anyone has an idea of what I can do?

Comment: Have you tried using python wheels to install Scipy?

Comment: Installing scipy with pip on windwows [almost never works](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scipy+install+windows+pip).

Comment: @Will_Panda I did, but it didn't worked as well.

Comment: @kazemakase Do you have any idea what I could do therefore?

Comment: @G4W yep, follow the link I posted and check out the existing answers. If none of them help, edit your post to explain clearly how your problem is different and why they did not work. Otherwise all we can do is point you there or repeat these answers, which does not really make sense, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it from the following binaries
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

These are unofficial precompiled binaries

Comment: Requirement 'scipy-0.17.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
scipy-0.17.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: You mentioned you are using python 3.x version right

Comment: then, you are trying to install 2.7 version

Comment: try scipy‑0.19.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl