# ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'scipy'

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

Hi I am bit of newby tinkering around with some machine learning, and I am getting an error in the python shell for scipy. I did a pip install for scipy in the windows command prompt and there are some odd looking errors when pip attempts to install. This is the simple little code I am using, any ideas to try for the scipy error?

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np
import scipy
from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, svm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\bbartling\\Documents\\Python\\test_SP data\\testElectData.csv')



df = df[['kWhDay','CDDbase55',]]
print(df.head())

# forecast_col = 'kWhDay'
X = np.array(df.drop(['kWhDay'],1))
y = np.array(df.drop(['CDDbase55'],1))
```

[image]

Comment: Read the docs (scipy + install) or any other question here asking for scipy install (there are probably > 100). Pip-based install of scipy on windows is nearly impossible (yes, it's also mentioned in the docs) and therefore your scipy is probably broken or uninstalled (the latter is probably the case because install will be rolled back).

Comment: possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875684/installing-scipy-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out on how to install python modules thru wheels. Good U tube video to make it work

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXIlclFQZVU